# How can i execute 2 seperate commands in a Dockerfile?

Tags: node.js, docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile that installs multiple services on a ubuntu baseimage such as npm, nodejs and ssh.
I want be able to ssh into the container and also run a node express application.
It works perfectly to run one of that. But i cant figure out how to start both services!
To run ssh i did:

```
CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd","-D"]
```

For the node application i clone a git repo and run:

```
CMD ["node" "app.js"]
```

Each of that runs perfectly.
But how can i execute both commands?
I tried putting them both in the CMD directive:

```
CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd","-D", "node", "app.js"]
```

I also tried to execute one of them with RUN:

```
RUN node app.js
CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd","-D"]
```

It executes but is than stuck at this point and doesnt continue to compute the image..
How can i execute `/usr/sbin/sshd -D` (which i need to run ssh) and also `node app.js`?

Heres the full Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt update && apt install  openssh-server sudo -y

RUN apt install git -y

RUN apt install nodejs -y

RUN apt install npm -y

RUN npm install express

RUN npm install better-sqlite3

RUN npm install morgan

RUN echo "PermitRootLogin yes">etc/ssh/sshd_config

RUN  echo 'root:root' | chpasswd

RUN git clone https://github.com/mauriceKalevra/Web2-Projekt.git

WORKDIR Web2-Projekt

RUN npm install


RUN service ssh start

EXPOSE 22


#CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd","-D", "&&", "node", "app.js"lss" ]

CMD ["node", "app.js"]
```

Comment: A container is usually a wrapper around a single command; if you have multiple commands to run, you'd normally run multiple containers.  But, conversely, a container is a wrapper around a single command; if you run `node app.js` on your host without Docker, would you actually need to ssh into that _command_?  I'd skip the ssh daemon entirely here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options are available to do this.

#### Option 1

Use a shell and `&&` to execute two commands.

```
FROM debian:stretch-slim as builder
CMD touch test.txt && ls
```

#### Option 2

Put all commands you want to execute in executable script `entrypoint.sh` and run that script in `CMD`

```
FROM debian:stretch-slim as builder
COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
CMD ./entrypoint.sh
```

entrypoint.sh

```sh
#!/bin/sh
touch test.txt
ls
```

### EDIT

Please note, that the commands will by default be executed sequentially so the second command will only be executed after the first. If your first process does never terminate, the second one will never start. Use `&` to execute commands in the background. For more information on how to run commands in parallel or sequentially please see [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/990423/how-can-i-run-multiple-commands-which-have-in-one-command-line).

Comment: Can you calrify what you mean by using a shell? I tried a executable script. The container would only execute the first command..

Comment: You cannot use array syntax if you use `&&` as you need a shell to interpret that. Check [this](https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/docker-tip-63-difference-between-an-array-and-string-based-cmd) out.

Comment: You need to start `sshd` in the background as well because the second command will only be executed after the first one was successful. As `sshd` does not terminate, the 2nd command is never executed.

Comment: You could also have a look at [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/990423/how-can-i-run-multiple-commands-which-have-in-one-command-line) which covers how to run task in parallel and/ or sequentially in bash.

Comment: Option 2 worked! Its importand to add a `&` after the first command to ensure its running in the background so the second command can execute!

Comment: I'll edit my answer to make that clear :)